# window.location() is not working in .aspx page

Tags: javascript

I have an aspx page and a asp textbox control which has ajax autoCompleteExtender. I want the page to be redirected to another page according to the selected element from the autocomplete list. But when I use

```
window.location()
```

nothing is happening, just the same page is refreshed. Here is my javascript;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectCity() {
        var str = document.getElementById('<%= txtSearchForDestination.ClientID %>').value;
        var array = str.split(",");
        var city = array[0].replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
        city = city.replace(/ /g, "+")
        var country = array[1].replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
        country = country.replace(/ /g, "+")
        window.location.href("City.aspx?city=" + city + "-" + country);
    }
</script>
```

The script is working, I tried it with like

> alert("City.aspx?city=" + city + "-" + country)

there is no problem. But when I want to redirect to that page it is not working. I also tried

> window.location("http://www.google.com")

it's not working as well.

What can be the problem ?

Comment: **Read** [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) and **look** in your JavaScript console. `location` is not a function. `location.href` is not a function. You might need to use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) as well for those query parameters, and none of that `replace(/ /g, '+')` silliness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
  window.location = 'City.aspx?city=' + city + '-' + country;
```

?

Comment: omg yes it is working now! I am trying to do it with paranthesis for an hour! thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a function, it's a property.

```
window.location.href = "City.aspx?city=" + city + "-" + country;
```

Comment: thanks, of course.. I think it is a result of working for too many hours.